# How to transfer transition animation from website to flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation

I liked the transition animation on one site - https://senkuro.com, how can I transfer it to flutter?
I found [google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-motion-flutter#0) but it seems to me that this is not what suits me.

Answer (score 0):

do this when calling a new route

eg:

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => YourScreen(),
    transitionsBuilder: (_, animation, __, child) {
      return FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: child,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you show how to use it in navigation? I misunderstood a little